# What does it mean for $g_{1}G^{'} = g_{2}G^{'}$ in cosets?

Tags: definition, quotient-spaces, quotient-group, quotient-set

I learned from here [Are all normal subgroups Abelian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770414/are-all-normal-subgroups-abelian) what does it mean for the left coset to be equal to the right coset. But I still do not understand what does it mean for a coset of two different representatives to be equal i.e. What does it mean for $g_{1}G^{'} = g_{2}G^{'}$  in cosets?

Could anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: it means that $g_2^{-1}g_1\in G'$

Comment: A coset is a set. Two cosets are equal iff they are equal as sets, i.e., each element of either one is an element of the other.

Comment: @Surb does not it mean that $g_{1} = g_{2}g $ for some $g$ in $G^{'}$ or that is wrong?

Comment: does not it mean that $g_{1} = g_{2}g $ for some $g$ in $G^{'}$ or that is wrong? @AnginaSeng

Comment: Yes it means that.

Comment: How I do not understand why @Berci could you please explain that to me in an answer?

Comment: Try to figure it out first yourself based on the comments here.

Comment: My struggle is that where the $g$ beside the $g_{1}$ has gone?@Berci

Comment: What means $g_2^{-1}g_1\in G'$ ? It means that $$\exists g\in G':g_2^{-1}g_1=g.$$

Comment: @Surb Thanks! got it.